# Use parameters inside @Formula Annotation

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to use @Param in @Formula annotations when defined in the actual JPA Method.

Lets say this is my Formula annotation for calculating distance between two points in Postgre.

```
   @Formula("(SELECT point(:lat, :lon) <@> (point(clubAddress.longitude, clubAddress.latitude)\\:\\:point) FROM club_address clubAddress WHERE clubAddress.id = id)")
```

And this is the actual method

```
List<ClubAddress> getClubAddressClosestBy(@Param("lat") double latitude, @Param("lon") double longitude);
```

When using this Spring complains that im not using the Param in the actual query which is true. Is there a way to "trick" Spring into thinking it?

Answer (score 0):

No, `@Formula`s are not parametrizable. Sorry.